How can I assign a keyboard shortcut to a process to open a Spotlight window and repopulate it specific filter(s) (eg. "Kind" == "Folder")
My current process to search for a specific directory listing uses Spotlight wth filters in a regular Finder window. I add file attribute filters to refine my search to folders only, and sometimes a last modified date range.
I'm looking for a process whereby a single keyboard shortcut can trigger a process to do this, preferably without buying some commercial automation software for macOS.
Current steps are:

type ^ + shift + spacebar which is my customised Spotlight shortcut.
type the text token I wish to use into the text field (eg "eBooks")
click on the little + icon/button below the text token field (top right corner) which adds a spotlight selection filter (see red outline in image below)

click on the filter's first attribute field, wait for it the menu to pop-up and then select "Kind" from the pop-up menu.
click on the second filter attribute field now populated with file kinds and select "Folder" from the menu.

Each time I do it these days I resent this time intensive process a little more. If I just search for the text with no "Kind" filter I get too many random files from the system libraries etc etc.
If a keyboard shortcut could be assign to that process, via applescript or perl, great, I'll give it a go.
Preparing screen shots for this question, I discovered a couple of "almost there" solutions but not quit there yet.

There's a button in the toolbar (or can be added to the default Finder window toolbar using right-click "customise toolbar" command) which groups files into file types, and one of those types is folders and seems to consistently list folders up top of the group rankings. So they aren't obscured "below the fold". See red highlight in image below.



I discovered just now I can save a spotlight search and that Save listing appears in the sidebar (this will be easy for me to lose until I muscle memory it into reality, but better than nothing). I can have an empty text token field (null) while having a Kind attribute == "Folder" filter saved as part of the search.  (See red…below.)


If there is a way to assign a keyboard shortcut to the Group files button in the window toolbar button (1) or to open a Finder window sidebar item in the Finder then I'm home and showered.
Happy to try an AppleScript or perl but wouldn't know where to start. prefer not to use commercial software for this small task (only).

In the Console.app filter field you can use proc:xxx etc to quickly add filter without using menu selections(see console help page). Is is possible to do this in the finder?

I don't think this is possible in Finder. the several steps outlined above are required I think.
